# Not able to change the value of element of array in for-loop in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, data-structures

I want to add one to the array values that are next to the current iteration.
Although at the end result is right, if we see the print(item) result, it still prints the old values.

```
 var arr3 = [1,2,3]
        
    for (index,item) in arr3.enumerated() {

        if index+1 == arr3.count {
            // Do nothing
        } else {
            arr3[index + 1] = arr3[index+1] + 1
        } 
        print(item)
    }
print(arr3)
```

Result :

1

2

3

[1,3,4]

Expected :

1

3

4

[1,3,4]

How is this possible?

Comment: The next element is incremented here : arr3[index + 1] = arr3[index+1] + 1. The current loop increment the next element in the array but when the next iteration comes, It prints the last one.

Comment: You're executing the `print(item)` **before** updating it. Move it to the last item of the for-loop.

Comment: Moved it, still the same result. 1
2
3
[1, 3, 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might expect the loop using `enumerated()` to behave the same as looping over the `indices` and having `let item = arr3[index]`:

```
for index in arr3.indices {
    let item = arr3[index]
    print(item)
    if index+1 != arr3.count {
       arr3[index + 1] += 1
    }
}
```

However, this is not true. `enumerated()` produces an `EnumeratedSequence<[Int]>`. (See the source code for [`EnumeratedSequence`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/stdlib/public/core/Algorithm.swift#L95) and [`enumerated()`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L67)). To create an `EnumeratedSequence`, the original array `arr3` is passed to its initialiser:

```
public func enumerated() -> EnumeratedSequence<Self> {
    return EnumeratedSequence(_base: self)
}
```

As you may know, `Array` is a ([copy-on-write](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-copy-on-write)) value type. When you modify `arr3` in the loop, a modified copy is created and assigned to `arr3`, and the array that the `EnumeratedSequence` has (i.e. the array over which the loop is iterating), is unaffected. `enumerated()` is sort of creating a "snapshot" of the array at the time when you called it, so all the `print(item)` will only print the old items.

Comment: why not `arr3[index + 1] += 1`?

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for reminding me. I was too fixated on the `enumerated()` vs `indices` difference, that I didn't pay much attention to fixing what's inside the loop.